# Call Function with Implicit Type Conversion

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

I have a class like this.

```
public class ForeignKey {
    public string Id {get;}
    public TableA TableA {get;}
    public TableB TableB {get;}
    public static implicit operator string(ForeignKey obj){ return obj.Id; }
    public override string ToString() { return Id; }
    /* various operator overloads */
}
```

I would like to have automatic type conversion on it so I can it use like a string. What I've done so far lets me use it in a number of places without an explicit cast. However, I can't figure out a way to call string functions without doing an explicit cast.

For example, I'd like to get this to work.

```
if (Key.EndsWith(someValue))
```

Currently I have to do this

```
if (((string)Key).EndsWith(someValue))
// or
if (Key.Id.EndsWith(someValue))
```

Is there a way to get it to work how I want?

Thanks

Comment: Key.Id is already string. Your last option Key.Id.EndsWith(someValue) should automatically work.

Comment: You can create a C# extension method for this with signature as public static KeyValue(this Key key){}

Comment: Right, Key.Id.EndsWith works but I would like to get Key.EndsWith to work.

Comment: create extension method...because ultimately you will have to check the Id value only. Check that inside the extension method.

Comment: I don't think you can make it work as desired, except by adding a `EndsWith` method to `ForeignKey`, either as an instance method or as an extension method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done, because member look-up operator `.` does not take members of types other than that of `ForeignKey` into consideration.

Section 7.4 explains the process.

> A member lookup of a name N with K type parameters in a type T is processed as follows:
>
> - First, a set of accessible members named N is determined
> - Next, if K is zero, all nested types whose declarations include type parameters are removed. If K is not zero, all members with a different number of type parameters are removed.
> - Next, if the member is invoked, all non-invocable members are removed from the set.
> - Next, members that are hidden by other members are removed from the set.
> - Next, interface members that are hidden by class members are removed from the set. This step only has an effect if T is a type parameter and T has both an effective base class other than object and a non-empty effective interface set.
> - Finally, having removed hidden members, the result of the lookup is determined:
>
>   > - If the set consists of a single member that is not a method, then this member is the result of the lookup.
>   > - Otherwise, if the set contains only methods, then this group of methods is the result of the lookup.
>   > - Otherwise, the lookup is ambiguous, and a binding-time error occurs.

Since C# does not consider conversion operators in the process of member resolution, your only option is to add the method to your class, either directly or through an extension.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I'll be adding a bunch of functions to call string functions.

Answer (score 3):

You can [create a extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) taking this Key as parameter.

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
  public static class Utilities
  {
    public static bool ValueEndsWith(this Key key, ref string valueToCheck)
    {
      return key.Id.EndsWith(valueToCheck);
    } 
  }
}
```

You can call it as `Key.ValueEndsWith(ref valueString)`;

Comment: Oh, I wasn't clear on that I wanted to directly call string functions. Not create a set of functions that calls the various string functions.